# asp.net core IFilterProvider filter attributes are not executing

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created an IFilterProvider for my asp.net mvc core 2.0 application. I am attempting to get the same functionality as [Phil Haack's Conditional Filter Provider](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/25/conditional-filters.aspx/)

I have registered the filter provider in the service collection as a singleton, but my attributes are not being executed. I can see the OnProvidersExecuting method being executed if i debug, but that is all.  The attributes work correctly if i statically add them to the controller actions.

The attributes I am adding are TypeFilterAttributes, not sure if that makes a difference.

I'd appreciate any advice you can give!

Here is the code:

```
public class PermissionFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    private readonly Func<ActionContext, IFilterMetadata>[] conditions;

    public PermissionFilterProvider()
    {
        conditions = new Func<ActionContext, IFilterMetadata>[]
        {
            (c) => c.HttpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Get.Method
                ? new PermissionAttribute(Permission.Read)
                : null,

            (c) => c.HttpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Post.Method
                ? new PermissionAttribute(Permission.Create)
                : null,

            (c) => c.HttpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Put.Method
                ? new PermissionAttribute(Permission.Write)
                : null,

            (c) => c.HttpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Delete.Method
                ? new PermissionAttribute(Permission.Delete)
                : null
        };
    }

    public int Order => 0;

    public void OnProvidersExecuted(FilterProviderContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnProvidersExecuting(FilterProviderContext context)
    {
        var filterMetas = conditions.Select(c => c(context.ActionContext)).OfType<IFilterMetadata>().First();

        Debug.WriteLine($"Adding Filter Metadata {filterMetas.GetType()} for action {context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName}.");
        context.Results.Add(
            new FilterItem(
                new FilterDescriptor(filterMetas, FilterScope.Global), 
                filterMetas
            )
        );
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Set's answer has put me on the path.

My PermissionAttribute class was unnecessarily complicated. The attribute is now just a simple marker, and i have a global PermissionFilter class which does the work if the attribute is present.
With all this in place the filter provider is working.

Here is the code for the attribute and global filter:

```
public class PermissionAttribute : Attribute, IFilterMetadata
{
    public PermissionAttribute(Permission Permissions)
    {
        this.Permissions = Permissions;
    }

    public Permission Permissions { get; private set; }
}

public class PermissionFilter : IAsyncResourceFilter
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationService authService;

    public PermissionFilter(IAuthorizationService authService)
    {
        this.authService = authService;
    }

    public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var action = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
        var attribute = context.Filters.OfType<PermissionAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();

        if(attribute != null)
        {
            var requirement = new PermissionsAuthorizationRequirement(attribute.Permissions);

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to reproduce your problem, I have created the following filter and your code works for me (`OnActionExecuted`, `OnActionExecuting` is called):

```
public enum Permission
{
    Read, Create, Write, Delete
}

public class PermissionAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public PermissionAttribute(Permission p) : this(typeof(PermissionAttribute))
    {}

    public PermissionAttribute(Type type) : base(type)
    {}

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // this is called
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // this is called
    }
}
```

---

If this is not what you want to achieve, please edit your question with your implementation of `PermissionAttribute`.

---

But if I understand your idea then the point is that you don't need to use [`TypeFilterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#typefilterattribute) at all and instead simply define your needed [filter type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#filter-types), like

```
public class PermissionAttribute : IActionFilter
{
      public PermissionAttribute(IMyDependency dependency)
      { ... }

      // IActionFilter interface implementation
}
```

as the main purpose of `TypeFilterAttribute` is to help resolve needed dependencies from DI container. And cause you use `FilterProvider` to create and attach filters to actions, you may directly inject needed dependencies to `FilterProvider` via the constructor and pass them when instantiating filter:

```
public PermissionFilterProvider(IMyDependency dependency)
{
    (c) => c.HttpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Get.Method
                ? new PermissionAttribute(dependency)
                : null,
    ...
}

// Note: IMyDependency implementation should be registered to DI container
```